# VLC - Close/minimise buttons missing

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I have VLC player latest version running on **Windows 10**.

I no longer see the `Close/minimise buttons` anymore on the top right.

[image]

Is VLC remove it on their newest update ? If so, is there a way to bring it back ?

Or

Is there a setting in VLC that I need to allow ?

Comment: Those controls are normally shown on the "row" just _above_ your highlighted area, opposite the file name on the far left.  Are you certain that your window pane doesn't simply have the top "row" cut off from your view?

Comment: That's all I see. No any other row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just press right click when a video playing, goto 'view ' option then uncheck full screen interface, now you will find minimize, close buttons

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you on <kbd>F</kbd>ullscreen mode?

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit fullscreen mode.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will elaborate just a bit, because my full screen mode does _not_ look like what he posted in his screen capture.

Comment: Hmm. <f11> is use to toggle full screen in my version of VLC (latest version 2.2.4)  ...

Comment: @Run5k My full screen looks the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @DavidPostill  To clarify for our studio audience it sounds like the root cause actually produces a hybrid answer.  Using version 2.2.4, if I press either the `F` key or the button on the lower left that says `Toggle the video in fullscreen` I don't see any interface unless I move the mouse cursor and pressing `Esc` will back out of that mode.  However, if I press `F11` I see the same interface that the question's author posted, but the `Esc` key does **not** back out of it.  I need to press `F11` again to see the `Close` and `Minimize` buttons that the author seeks.